# What's the quickest way to get a defined section of an array? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array `var testArray= ["juice", "cow", "foo", "pig", "cat"]`

and a parameter string `foo"-"cat`

How can I get the result `foo, pig, cat`

Comment: Do you want the 3rd, 4th and 5th elements or the numbers 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: the numbers, the array isn't always in numerical order, I just want to be able to define the first and last array value and get everything in between

Comment: why is the parameter a string and not two numeric parameters ?

Comment: So if your array was `[5,2,3,1,4]` and your parameter was `3-5`, is `[3,4,5]` still the expected result?

Comment: No, an easier explination is   var testArray= ["juice", "cow", "foo", "pig", "cat"] I want "foo"-"cat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your revised question in the comments, you should use something like this:

```
> var testArray= ["juice", "cow", "foo", "pig", "cat"]
> testArray.slice(testArray.indexOf("foo"), testArray.indexOf("cat") + 1)
Array [ "foo", "pig", "cat" ]
```

This assumes a number of things:

1. You know in advance which of the two elements occurs first
2. You know that both elements definitely exist

If your starting point is a string "foo-cat", you can use `"foo-cat".split("-")` to obtain the two word separately.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not being more clear in the original question

Comment: No problem. You should edit your question to make it clearer, so that it is more useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get from the element that equals to `3` to the element that is equal to `5` use:

```
array.slice(array.indexOf(3), array.indexOf(5) + 1)
```

With this call we take all array values with indexes between `array.indexOf(3)` and `array.indexOf(5)`

Comment: There is no fifth array element. You said it yourself, arrays are zero based.

Comment: There is no index 5. But the array has 5 elements.

Comment: I don't know when 3 occurs in the array, I want from the first value in the array that equals 3 to the value that equals 5, they are all strings and not in a numerical sequential order. sometimes I have 4, 4a, 4b, 5

Comment: Just use his answer except replace 2 and 5 with array.indexOf(3) and array.indexOf(5)